# input[type=number] in Google Chrome won't accept latlng from Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

Here's a snippet of a coordinate picker I made with Google Maps JavaScript API v3:

```
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('lat').value = e.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('long').value = e.latLng.lng();
    map.panTo(e.latLng);
    if (map.getZoom() < 14) {
        map.setZoom(14);
    }
    marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
});
```

`#lat` and `#long` are `Number`-typed `input` elements. But when I submit, Chrome says

> Please enter a valid value. The two nearest valid values are 3 and 4

I tried wrapping the values with `parseFloat()` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome treats numbers a bit differently, you also have to use the step attribute.

In you case the following should work:

```
<input type="number" step="any" />
```

You can change the step to any decimal you want (like 0.1, 0.001), but any should be the best for your problem